# Disable creating new taxonomy terms in term reference field

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I need to limit the user to the already create terms through `admin/structure/taxonomy/VOCABULARY/add` in auto complete mode, But when the user types new terms it will be added to the list. How do I can limit the user to the terms list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [content taxonomy](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) module adds additional functionality to prevent new terms with the autocomplete widget.

> **D7 and Content Taxonomy**
>
> The module provides extensions to Drupal's
>   core Taxonomy Term Reference Fields. At the moment, following
>   extensions are available:
>
> - Parent term selector in the field settings (for options lists)
> - Options for new terms in autocomplete (Autocomplete Deluxe widget supported as
>     well):
>
>   - Allow and insert new terms (default behaviour)
>   - Allow and insert new terms into a separate vocabulary
>   - Deny any new terms

Comment: I guess there is a problem with Drupal ftp, I can't download any module. I will test this module when they fix their ftp server